# Find the identical values in one array and its equivalent pair in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays like this 
`a = point1[:2]`, `b = point2[:2]`
which are of equal length. Now I want to find the repeated values in `a` and their respective indices in `b`. Once I have these indices I want to calculate root mean square.

I have tried the following:

```
b = point2[:2] 
idx = np.argsort(b)
sorted_z_predval = b[idx]
vals, idx_start, count = 
    np.unique(sorted_z_predval, return_counts=True, return_index=True)
filt = np.split(idx, idx_start[1:])
vals = vals[count >1]
b_uniq = filter(lambda x: x.size>1, filt)`
```

Now I got the indices where the values are repeated more than once. I need to find the equivalent pair indices in `a = point1[:2]`
i'm struck in this point.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems a simple thing. Are there any sound reason not to try to code it yourself?

Comment: have a look at [np.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality that will do these type of operations in an efficient and vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = npi.indices(b, npi.unique(a))
```

Note that you can use for instance `npi.indices(b, npi.unique(a), missing=-1)`, to get values of -1 in idx, where there is no corresponding entry in b.

Comment: no it is not working. i'm getting KeyError: u'Not all keys in that are present in this

Comment: here b_unique has the list of indices which has to be mapped in 'a = point1[:2]'. The above solution doesn't work in this case

Comment: "Now I want to find the repeated values in a and their respective indices in b."; thats exactly what the given solution does. As the function is telling you though, not all repeated values in a are present in b. How you want the npi.indices function to react to that situation, you can control using the 'missing' kwarg. As you found out the default is to raise an exception.

Comment: if you see the code 'b_unique' found the repeated values which is unequal length compared 'a' length. Because it selected only the elements that are only repeated. Even the above solution doesn't work. It gives me Valueerror Operands cannot be broadcast together with shapes 2, 3

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to say. However, if you take some time and read the docstring of the npi.indices function, I am absolutely positive it is capable of solving all problems of the type you are talking about.